# Generate REST API documentation

Tags: rest, maven, jakarta-ee, javadoc, jersey-2.0

Is there a way to auto-generate a [ZOHO](https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#products)-style documentation of my Jersey Rest Services? This is one of the best REST documentations I have seen so far. I'm open to alternatives.

[Swagger](http://swagger.io/) also looks promising but I don't see how to generate it. It seems like it needs a YAML style documentation.

Can I generate it from javadoc somehow?

I'd prefer to generate the docs via Maven.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate swagger-ui from Javadoc by using [Enunciate](http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/), which has a Swagger module. First, you need to add the maven plugin to your pom file; e.g.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.webcohesion.enunciate</groupId>
        <artifactId>enunciate-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${enunciate.version}</version>
        <executions>
           <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>docs</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <configFile>enunciate.xml</configFile>
                    <docsDir>${project.build.directory}</docsDir>
                  </configuration>
           </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

where 'enunciate.xml' contains your project specific configurations and looks like this:

```
<enunciate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.webcohesion.com/schemas/enunciate-2.0.0-M.3.xsd">

    <application root="/rest" />

</enunciate>
```

Then run `mvn package` and it will generate Swagger documentation files from your Javadoc.

p.s. taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340735/using-javadocs-to-generate-swagger-document/33667644#33667644).

Answer (score 0):

Adding swagger to jersey based services is not too complicated. 
See these detailed [steps](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5) on how to go about it:

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to document your REST API, it's not difficult to set up. There are some instructions [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5). To summarize:

### Adding Swagger dependencies

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### Setting up Swagger

Add the following to your [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class (change the values according to your needs):

```java
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public MyApplication() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources,com.example.project");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

Build your project, start your server and access `http://localhost:8080/app/api/swagger.json` (the URL might be different in your environment) to get the JSON which documents your API.

### Setting up Swagger UI

Download Swagger UI from [GitHub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) and copy the content from the `dist` folder to your web content folder. I usually create a folder called `api-docs` to store all Swagger UI files.

Open Swagger UI's `index.html` and change the URL which refers to the `swagger.json`:

```javascript
var swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/app/api/swagger.json",
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container"
});
```

Access `http://localhost:8080/app/api-docs` (the URL might be different in your environment). The Swagger UI with your API documentation should be there.

### More information

- You always can [customize Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#customize) to fit your needs.
- Swagger reads [JAX-RS annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html) to generate the documentation. Additionally, you can use [Swagger annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#swagger-core-annotations) to improve it.