# Swagger 2 / Springfox for Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

I have configured in my Spring MVC application Swagger 2 / [Springfox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/). Unfortunately I do not see the description of Javadoc documentation.

Has anyone already successfully used it? Can anyone give me a hint? I know Swagger 1. It takes the documentation, params... from javadoc of the controller

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340735/using-javadocs-to-generate-swagger-document)

Answer (score 1):

Add `@ApiOperation` to the controller method.
Here is the [wiki](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apioperation).