# How to generate Swagger UI from javadocs?

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, swagger, swagger-ui

I can generate swagger UI on my Spring boot application from `@Api` `@ApiOperation`, `@ApiResponses` annotations.

These annotations makes code a bit dirty. I wonder, how I can generate swagger documentation for my API-endpoints from javadocs.

Comment: What do you mean by javadoc? 
I know javadoc but I don't understand how you could use javadoc to generate a  swagger/openapi specification?

Comment: @petet I mean generate from comments on top of each controller method.

Comment: Related: [Using Javadocs to generate Swagger document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32340735/113116)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Javadocs to generate Swagger document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340735/using-javadocs-to-generate-swagger-document)

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer* - **No, not really.**

*Longer answer:* Swagger files contains much more information than the code - for example @ApiOperation as you already mentioned.
I would recommend to stick with Swagger Maven Plugin that I assume you already use. Our team have tried to auto-generate clients to run API tests against the generated swagger file, and so far spring-fox and other solutions doesn't come close to swagger-maven-plugin or hand coding the file.