# How to use swagger with ResourceConfig in jersey ?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0, grizzly

I am developing a REST api and trying to use Swagger along with Jersey to do so.
I am following the guide given here :- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5
I use `ResourceConfig` instead of the `Application` class and have modified the steps in the guide accordingly. I am deploying the API on grizzly.

Here , is the main file :-

```
package com.example;

import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.*;

/**
 * Main class.
 *
 */
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/";

    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        // in com.example package
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.example");
        rc.register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
        rc.register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.2");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("resources/api");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("io.swagger.resources");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to access the swagger.json at the url `http://localhost:8080/swagger.json`, I am getting a 500, Request Failed error.
Why is that and how can I debug it ?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33681371/2587435). Probably related

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks! It was the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this project :

https://github.com/sofien-hamdi/rest-mongo

I've configured it using BeanConfig.

```
package com.kt.examples.rs.configuration;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.WadlResource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.kt.examples.rs.controller.UserController;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers;

@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

  public JerseyConfig() {
    this.registerEndpoints();
    this.configureSwagger();
  }

  private void registerEndpoints() {
    this.register(UserController.class);
    this.register(WadlResource.class);
    // http://localhost:9090/v1/application.wadl
  }

  private void configureSwagger() {
    this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
    this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
    config.setConfigId("spring-boot-jaxrs-swagger");
    config.setTitle("Spring boot jaxrs swagger integration");
    config.setVersion("v1");
    config.setBasePath("/");
    config.setResourcePackage("com.kt.examples.rs");
    config.setPrettyPrint(true);
    config.setScan(true);
    // http://localhost:9090/v1/swagger.json
  }
}
```

Comment: Please also include the essential part of the answer here.  SO is for long term use and links may change.