# How to debug eclipselink moxy Json issue with jersey?

Tags: jersey-2.0, moxy

i'm using eclipselink moxy inside jersey but i'm totally clueless how to enable any useful output from moxy besides:

SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class ...

Is there anything i'm missing? Should jersey logging contain more clues?

Tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope someone can use this information:

I debugged through it and found a very good Breakpoint:

In org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.java:1103 is a catch block which contains the necessary Information needed to understand exactly what is wrong.

I do not understand at all why my Eclipse *Exception* Breakpoint didn't hit it but yeah...

I will find out why this useful message is removed when the exception bubbles up.

I'm using Jersey 2.41 with eclipse moxy 2.6

Comment: You can also use a [generic ExceptionMapper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33684719/2587435) to catch all exceptions.

Comment: @peeskillet nope not in this case. The exception is caught and null is returned. There is no information in the following exception any more.