# Request sent by the client is syntatically incorrect

Tags: java, jersey

I am trying to upload a file using Jersey multipart. Here is my code:

```java
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/test")
public class Tester {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces
    public Response test(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream file, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        return Response.status(200).entity(fileDetail.getFileName()).build();
    }
}
```

Every time I run this code, I get a 400:

> the request sent by the client is syntatically incorrect

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a stacktrace logs on the server? Can you post that also. The image looks ok.

Comment: i mean the stack trace is clean.

Comment: I don't know then. What you've show looks good. Without any error stacktace, it's hard to debug. Check out the  first part of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33684719/2587435). Add the `DebugMapper` to your application. See if you can get a stack trace that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually removing the `Content-Type: multipart/formdata` from the header solved the problem. Thank you all for the suggestions